How can I uninstall XuanZhi VirtualBox (LDPlayer)?
I tried to update my Windows 11 to the latest version (24H2). During the update I saw the following message:

I have no idea what this "VirtualBox (LDPlayer)" is, but I went into "Add and Remove Programs" and looked for it, and found this:

I clicked "Uninstall" and got the following message:

This is very strange as I have no F drive at all (only C and D), and also do not know what this XuanZhi is.
What can I do to proceed with the Windows update?

https://www.ldplayer.net/ ? Also, it looks like the registry points at old location of uninstaller and you had F drive before. I'm confused that you are confused about both. Is and was this always your device?

@Destroy666 yes, it was always my device. I gave it for repair once, but it is hard to believe that the technician installed something. In any case, now I only want to proceed with the Windows update - what can I do?

Use Everything to find the real location of DPlayer's duninst.exe if it exists somewhere else, then point the registry record at that. If it doesn't exist, install it to check if that overrides the entry.  Or you could try to manually remove the app leftovers from registry, but that's a lot more complex. BCUninstaller could maybe help, but it could be confused about non-existent F: drive too.
